# Can't find the window for a process whose status is `Sl`

Tags: gnome, process, gnome-classic

I am under Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome Classic as desktop environment.

I have a process, whose status is `Sl`, see below:

```
$ ps  aux | grep PDFXC
t        20363  0.1  0.0 2676268 6436 pts/61   Sl    2015  13:03 /home/t/programs/PDFXCview.exe bash4.3.pdf
```

What does `Sl` mean?

I don't remember whether I have tried to kill it by right clicking and selecting "close". Maybe or maybe not.
But now I can't find the window for the process in the desktop environment's panel.
Is it still possible to find its window, and make it to the front of the desktop environment?

Answer (score 1):

From [`man ps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ps.1.html):

```
PROCESS STATE CODES

  Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output
  specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state of
  a process:

       D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
       R    running or runnable (on run queue)
       S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
       T    stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is
            being traced
       W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
       X    dead (should never be seen)
       Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by
            its parent

  For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional
  characters may be displayed:

       <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
       N    low-priority (nice to other users)
       L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
       s    is a session leader
       l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads
            do)
       +    is in the foreground process group
```

(Since you used `aux`, you're running `ps` in BSD mode.)

So you have a multithreaded process which is currently sleeping.

Comment: Thanks. How can I bring the process's window to the front?

Comment: @Tim for that part, I've flagged your question as a dupe.

Comment: If I can't  bring the process to the front, can I save the unsaved change to the file opened by the process?

Comment: @Tim unlikely. Depends on the app. But usually, nope.